# iOS: Generate apple developer certificate based on distribution certificate

Tags: ios

I have apple distribution certificate:
https://monosnap.com/file/EJsxBtS13zMUGsFeoOIdoKhmpJYaLt

How can I generate the developer certificate with the same ID?

Comment: Why do you need to generate your separate developer certificate by the way? Use Xcode automatic signing with your distribution team and development certificate will be created and fetched for you.

Comment: XCode generates certificate with another identifier and I need the same as on screenshot

Comment: @AyanSengupta Also the automatic signed id differs from one, the app uses in AppStoreConnect

Comment: Developer certificate identifier will always differ from the distribution certificate identifier even if you belong to the same distribution team. Not really sure what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @AyanSengupta I signed automatically certificates. It's ID is L4JFK54664. Now in MS App Center (CI/CD) I need to upload .mobileprovision and .p12 cert. Where can I get them? I hav .p12 cert, but how can I generate .mobileprovision for it and should ID's be the same?

Comment: Goto Xcode > Preferences > Accounts tab. Certificates are there in your keychain from where you can export it as .p12

Comment: @AyanSengupta And what about for .mobileprovision for it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192285/discussion-between-ayan-sengupta-and-drevival).

Answer (score 1):

> How can I generate the developer certificate with the same ID?

There's no need for that. Every certificate has a different ID -- you don't need one that matches your distribution certificate.